# No module named 'appium' but I've installed it

Tags: python, android, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

I've installed appium on my system and use:

```
from appium import webdriver
```

by python3.6.

but in other code when I use it by python3.8 return me:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appium'

what's the problem with this error?!

Comment: many packages are for specific python versions.  install the one for 3.8 using its pip rather than that of 3.6.

Comment: are you using virtual environment? make sure the interpreter you use to run this code is the same interpreter in the venv where you've installed the package (under `you_venv/bin/python`)

Answer (score 1):

The basic crux of the problem is that those 2 python versions are not accessing the same location of installed pip modules. Try using the `python -m pip install SomePackage` method to call pip of specific Python Binary.

This snippet will help.

```
python38 -m pip install Appium-Python-Client
```

Not sure, how you manage those versions of python, but the basic gist of invoking specific pip version works.
Try `whereis pip` or `which pip` to ensure the correct pip is being called.